# Ввод двумерного массива с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 10 // Размер матрицы

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int i, j, sum = 0;  // Описание переменных
    int E[N][N];        // Описание массива
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Матрица - "<< N <<" X " << N << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)  // Заполнение матрицы
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            E[i][j] = rand() % 10;  // Случайными числами
            cout << E[i][j] << " "; // Вывод строки матрицы
        }
        cout << "\n";    // переход на следующую строку
    }
    for (i = 0, j = N - 1; i < N; i++, j--) // цикл подсчета суммы
        sum += E[i][j]; // Суммируем
    cout << "Cумма элементов матрицы = "<< sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как ввести массив `E[N][N]` с клавиатуры? получилось только определить с помощью `#define`

Comment: Имеешь в виду как ввести размер, или как заполнить не рандомными значениями?

Comment: Да, именно как ввести размер

Comment: Двумерный массив в Си может быть только фиксированного размера. Обычно создают класс с плавающими размерами используя память из кучи. Очень подходит реализация класса Matrix здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class

Answer (score 1):

Работает, но так писать не стоит,

```
size_t n, m;
std::cin >> n >> m;
int** data= new int*[n];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    data[i] = new int[m];
}
... 
В конце, когда массив не нужен
... 
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    delete[] data[i];
}
delete[] data;
```

А так стоит

```
size_t n, m;
std::cin >> n >> m;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data(n, std::vector(m));
```